# What topics fall under architecture?

Tags: architecture, terminology

I am an experienced coder. During the time I learnt C#, I followed a set of topics eg serialisation, exception handling, graphics, etc.

However, what topics are there in architecture and software design?

My list contains the concept of roundtrips, tiers, layering, is there anything else?

Thanks

Comment: I answered to help. But not really a programming question. Might be better suited for different site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the architectural level we are concerned about:

- Services
- Components
- Security
- Infrastructure
- Backward/forward compatibility (migration, dual phase, etc)
- Scalability
- Reliability
- Federation
- Standards (not necessarily industry standards, just consistency)

Architecture is just as much about non-technical communication and business strategy as it is about anything technical. Architects are responsible for translating business goals into systems, which are implemented by developers and technicians.

As far as your existing list - "tiers" is a high-level development concept, while I would consider "roundtrips" relatively low-level. At an architectural level, and even a high-level software design level, "roundtrips" is an implementation detail of the communication between systems, and is not very interesting until it starts impacting one of the areas listed above. I'm not sure what you mean by "layering".

Comment: A good start - the only major omission I'd like to add is the reuse of standards, reference architectures and systems.  True architetcure isn't just worrying about the "illities" when designing a system - but aligning it with existing parts of the architecture.

So to the list of topics I'd add Architectural Frameworks and Reference Architectures

Answer (score 0):

disaster recovery, scalability, caching, throughput, integration, security

These are just a few.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find a lot of <strike>buzz words</strike> topics:

- [Design Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design#Design_concepts)
- [Architectual patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

Although the list is exhastive, I tried to cover most basic points:

- [Functional requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirements)
- [Non-functional requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)
- [Architectural patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_%28computer_science%29)
- [Architecture models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Architectural_Model)
- [Design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29)
- [Anti-patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)
- [Application security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_security)